# Present Python variable in HTML Template in Django

Tags: html, django, django-views

I have a value extracted from JIRA API showing a total for a particular project.

When I print the value, I can see the correct values and these are clearly being stored in the variable.

I want to add these values to a template page in a `<p>` tag, but no matter what method I try, it just doesn't render.

Could someone please advice? :)

**views.py**

```
# Emergency Changes Query
jira_emergency_changes = jira.search_issues('labels = new-emerging-audit AND resolution = Unresolved').total

# Open Issues Query
jira_open_issues = jira.search_issues('project = UTILITY AND status = Open').total

# Open JIRA Ticket Total Query
jira_open_tickets = jira.search_issues('project = "UTILITY" AND status not in (Closed, Completed, Resolved) ORDER BY created DESC').total
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Emergency Changes</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{jira_emergency_changes}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your view and your template?

Comment: @IainShelvington Apologies, added above. I've tried adding to the render with no success, I tried to converting to javascript variable and calling as an id but nothing - I assume it is something super simple that I'm just not familiar with :)

Comment: Where is your view code, where you render the template? Add the variable you want to the context dict when you call render

Comment: @IainShelvington indeed, it was adding the variable to the context dict, thank you so much! :)